# Delete Github status checks from an old Netlify app

Tags: github, netlify

I connected a Netlify app with one of my repositories so when I had a pull request to the `main`branch it will trigger some status checks...

Like this:
[image: Status checks]

But then when I removed my website on Netlify the status checks are still running on my Github repository.

How can I delete these status checks? They run forever because my app on Netlify not longer exists.

What I have tried:

- I have detached Netlify from the App Settings of my repo.
- I have done several pull requests to the main branch and it still runs the checks

What I expect to happen is to delete the status checks... not just to prevent a failed status.